# Unable to change the proxy settings to localhost and port 8080

Tags: browser, proxy

I am trying to record a script using Jmeter script recorder, which requires to run the request from the browser with proxy set to Manual, localhost and port(say) 8080.

When I changed the proxy of the browser to localhost and port to 8080, I  lose internet, I see the message "The proxy server is refusing connections". I tried stopping the firewall but that does not seem to help.

I see same error when I user http://localhost i.e. Connection refused, but I am able to ping localhost successfully.

```
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that, unless I "Start" the Jmeter recording controller, I would not be able to access the URL/internet.